# Create same type of two tags within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a little problem but can't solve it. I try it but can't make any solution. I want to create two  tags in a div using JQuery but can't. I give my code below and also its output and what output I want. Thank you.

HTML :

```
    <ul id="tagCloud">
        <li id="tagcloud_li1">Item1</li>
        <li id="tagcloud_li">Item2</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="vis">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #tagCloud li{
           display:none;
        }
```

JavaScript :

```
        $(function() {
                var liArray = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
                var list_item = [];
                for(var i=0; i < liArray.length ;i++){
                    list_item.push($(liArray[i]).text());
                    var get_item_value = ($(liArray[i]).text());
                        $('#vis').find('.set_texts').wrapInner('<text>');

                }

              });
```

This code shows output :

```
     <div id="vis">
          <text>
               <text></text>      //text within text
          </text>
     </div
```

But I want to get this output :

```
     <div id="vis">
          <text></text>
          <text></text>      //text after text
     </div>
```

How I can do it?

Comment: try [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) something like this ```$('#vis').find('.set_texts').append($('<text>'))```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** to loop through the list items along with **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**:

```
$('#tagCloud li').each(function() {
    $('#vis').append('<text></text>');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zxp8/)**

Answer (score 0):

can try **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** , **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

use **html()**  when you want to total replace html of `#vis`

use **.append()** when you want to add new section with previous one

for more see their reference link

```
$('#vis').html('<text></text><text></text>');

$('#vis').append('<text></text><text></text>');
```

Comment: In this code there is a loop. This loop depends on the number of 'li'. I want to create more then one <text> depend on the number of 'li'.

Comment: $('#vis').append('<text></text>'); then use this one

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
                var liArray = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
                var list_item = [];
                for(var i=0; i < liArray.length ;i++){
                  $text = $("<text>");
                  $text.text($(liArray[i]).text());
                  list_item.push($text);  
                  list_item.forEach(function(ele) {
                    $("#vis").append(ele);
                  })
                }
              });
```

Working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/hidij/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0 ; i< count; ++i)
  $("#vis").append("<text></text>");
```

Comment: may be not to you buddy but it does solve his problem.